# Взаимодействие таблиц User, Student, Teacher

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvc

Делаю подобие школьного сайта.
В приложении MVC 4 заимплементил кастомный membership provider, соответственно при помощи code first entity framework сгенерировал 2 таблицы:

```
     public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

теперь, когда пришло время создавать такие таблицы как Pupil и Teacher, не знаю как с ними поступить
т.е. как должна выглядеть класс Pupil?
должен ли он быть как-то отнаследован от User или просто создать связь один ко одному между таблицами Pupil и User, Teacher и User?

Comment: Все зависит от того, что из себя представляют сами сущности `Pupil` и `Teacher`. Если эти сущности должны иметь возможность авторизироваться, то у таблиц `Pupil` и `Teacher` обязательно должно быть поле `IdUser`, которое является внешним ключом, связанным с полем `User.Id`

Comment: да, они должны иметь возможность входить на сайт. Т.е. нужно создать свзять один к одному?

Comment: Да. Нужно создать 2 связи "один к одному": `Pupil - User` и `Teacher - User`

Comment: Тогда получается, что в таблице User будет куча ключей PupilId, TeacherId, etc. и только один из этих ключей будет заполнен, что мне кажется не очень хорошей идеей.

Comment: Нет, вы не правы! Я же выше написал: `у таблиц Pupil и Teacher обязательно должно быть поле IdUser, которое является внешним ключом, связанным с полем User.Id`. Грубо говоря, ученик и учитель должны знать, какие у них данные для авторизации, а не наоборот.

Comment: По хорошему нужно использовать классическое наследование от User, а детали реализации оставить на "совести" EF

Comment: С другой стороны, если в производных классах будет много отличных дополнительных полей, то оптимальнее будет не наследовать от User, а иметь ссылку на него в виде навигационного свойства. Хоть это и неправильно с точки зрения ООП.

Comment: может скачать учебный проект Университет Контосо и изучить его ???